# Find $ \max \Im( W(- exp(x)) exp(-x) ) $ for real $x$.

Tags: calculus, optimization, harmonic-functions, lambert-w

Define the reals $x,y$ as

$$ y = \max \Im ( W ( - exp(x)) exp(-x) ) $$

Where $W$ is the standard Lambert W function and $\Im$ means the imaginary part.

How to find $x$ and $y$ ?

Closed forms ( allowing integrals , sums etc ) , contour integrals , numerical methods ??

I know how to express the local COMPLEX max on the complex plane for an analytic function by a contour integral.

I also know the Cauchy-Riemann equations that related the real and imaginary parts of an analytic function by differential equations.

Yet this does not appear to help me.
Maybe it should help me , but i do not see how.

I ask here for a case of the $W$ function , because i do not want to ask too General questions.
But i am also intrested in General methods ofcourse.

Comment: Yeah you forgot a bracket !! It is W ( - exp(x) )! Exp(-x)

Comment: Original comment of someone else is removed ...

Comment: If we could express the imaginary part without any [complex component functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ComplexComponents/), then we could differentiate and find a real only equation to solve, but so far we can just write $\max\ \frac i2e^{-x}\left(\frac{|y|^2}y-y\right),y=W(-e^x)$. Apparently [$|W(z)|=W(|z|)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/19/03/), but this identity is numerically false